# How do I add a launcher to unity for "gksudo "gnome-open %u""?

Tags: unity, launcher

How do I create a new launcher for Drag & Drop `gksudo "gnome-open %u"`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this (*I'm at mobile, I can't make it more specific until I get home but I think you will understand*):

**1)** Right click at the Desktop and choose "Create a Launcher".

[image]

**2)** Paste the name and the command you want, choose the icon you want and hit "OK".

[image]

**3)** Drag the launcher you just create to the Unity Launcher.

[image]

**4)** Congratulations, you have your launcher done!

[image]

Comment: That works, but when I delete the launcher from the desktop, it is also gone from the dash. Am i missing something?

Comment: Instead of deleting, just move it to ~/.local/share/applications/ ;-)